# Vector Inequality.

Tags: vector-spaces

Given that $|a|=|b|=1$ and $c=a\times b$ then maximum value of:
$$|(a+2b+3c).((2a+3b+c)\times(3a+b+2c))|$$
And I know this is the box product:
$$[(a+2b+3c),(2a+3b+c),(3a+b+2c)]$$
And hence the volume of these made into parallelopiped . I can say that:
$$|a+2b+3c|\le|a|+2|b|+3|c|=6$$
with obviously rotation of a,b,c involved. Hence volume is atmax $6^3$ when they are independent, but since they aren't I'm confused what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\begin{bmatrix} a+2b+3c & 2a+3b+c & 3a+b+2c  \end{bmatrix} = A \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c  \end{bmatrix}$, where
$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 3 & 1 & 2  \end{bmatrix}$, and
$\langle x, y \times z \rangle = \det \begin{bmatrix} x & y & z  \end{bmatrix}$. (Note that $\det A = -18$.)

Hence 
\begin{eqnarray}
|\langle a+2b+3c , (2a+3b+c)\times(3a+b+2c) \rangle| &=& |\det A \det \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c  \end{bmatrix}| \\
&=& 18 |\det \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c  \end{bmatrix}| \\
&=& 18 | \det \begin{bmatrix} a & b & a \times b  \end{bmatrix}| \\
&=& 18 | \det \begin{bmatrix} a \times b & a & b \end{bmatrix}| \\
&=& 18 | \langle a \times b, a \times b \rangle | \\
&=& 18 \|a \times b \|^2
\end{eqnarray}
Now choose $a,b$ of unit length to maximise $\|a \times b \|$.

Comment: I tend to forget that [xa+yb+zc,...,...]=matrix{x,y,z\\...\\...}*[a,b,c] thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some honest algebraic manipulation, we get the magnitude of the triple product is $18|a\times b\cdot c|$. It is well-known that $|a\times b\cdot c|$ is the volume of the parallelopiped spanned by $a$, $b$ and $c$. This volume is maximized when (1) the area of the base spanned by $a$ and $b$ is maximized and (2) the norm of the height vector $c$ (perpendicular to the base as $c=a\times b$) is maximized. Both maximization can be simultaneously achieved when $a$ is perpendicular to $b$. So the answer is 18.

Comment: "some honest algebraic manipulation", would you show that?

Comment: Expand the expression using distributive law.

Comment: that gives |(a+2b+3c.(2ab+4ac+9ba+6bc+3ca+cb))| with some of them cross products

Comment: You can do better than that. Note that for cross product, $a\times b=-b\times a$.

Comment: |5abc+2bac+3cba|?

Comment: Also for triple product, it also costs a sign to switch two factors. Use it in your manipulation.

Comment: 2bac=-2abc, 3cba=-3abc so it's zero?